# how to make simple responsive and adaptive design for input form in html

Tags: html

Help me please, how to make the following:
Input  form (input form should consist of input and submit html elements) should be 100% width (with some small padding) on devices like tablets and smaller. On the desktops, it should take 50% of the width and be horizontally centered.

for example:

[desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7gw3.png)

[tablets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/594Xw.png)

Comment: Your question is too broad for StackOverflow - please narrow it down, give more details, show what you tried. [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  max-width: 601px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.left {
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 25px;
  border: 1px dashed #f0f
}
.right {
  float: right;
  width: 80px;
  min-height: 25px;
  border: 1px dashed #00f
}
input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
}
button {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="right">
    <button>Search</button>
  </div>
  <div class="left">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/owmL4qnz/) also.